# Xpath from JScript

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium and I want to know how the value to the text box gets loaded when there is no value showing in HTML tag :

```
<input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="5" value="" title="Qty" class="quantity-input qty"
```

Or is it getting data from jscript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click','.quantity-plus',function(){
        var qty = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#qty').val());
        if(qty < 99999)
        {   
        var moq = jQuery('input[name=opinions]:checked').attr('data-moq');
        var incrementquantity = jQuery('input[name=opinions]:checked').attr('data-incrementquantity');
        var incrementmode = jQuery('input[name=opinions]:checked').attr('data-incrementmode');
        var qty = jQuery.trim(jQuery('#qty').val());
        jQuery('.moqerror').html('');
        if(Number(qty) >= Number(moq) && parseInt((qty-moq)%incrementquantity) == 0)
        {
            var newqty = parseFloat( parseFloat(qty) + parseFloat(incrementquantity));
            jQuery('#qty').val(newqty);
            updateEstimatePrice();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the script. `value` attribute is being set by [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
var newqty = parseFloat( parseFloat(qty) + parseFloat(incrementquantity));
jQuery('#qty').val(newqty);
```

I am confused as to why you have '[XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)' in the title of the question, which makes me think I am misunderstanding something.

**EDIT: Regarding the question of Selenium:**

So this seems a bit open ended - but I'll just give you how I would do it:

Prerequistes:

1. [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) testing framework
2. [promises](http://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises)
3. webdriverjs's [control flow using promises](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive#Understanding_the_API)
4. How angular protractor [uses promises](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/control-flow)

Assuming you are ok with with that:

First, setup Selenium with protractor, (which is a big task) and then you could do this (untested):

```
describe("Checking selectall, ", function() {
  it("exists,", function() {
    var qty = element(By.css('input#qty'));
    expect(browser.isElementPresent(qty)).toEqual(true);
    it("clicks loads with a value", function() {
      qty.getAttribute("value").then(function(data) {
          return console.log("qty.value", data);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: ok thanks, so in selenium how do i retrieve value from the textbox, since it shows 50 inside textbox when page is loaded but value is not shown inside the <input> tag